# regex document.write pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get a string in between single quotes from the following `document.write('mystring')` I have tried the following pattern `\'[A-Za-z0-9]+\'` but I want the string without the single quote marks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match("/'([a-z0-9]+)'/i", $str, $matches);
//string contents are now in `$matches[1]`
```

You may also want to use `\w` or even something else to do the capturing unless you are absolutely sure that the string you want to acquire is purely alphanumeric.  This also assumes that only apostrophes are used and not quotes.

Comment: The `?` is unnecessary here, because the "end marker" (the apostrophe) is not itself a valid character in the class.

Comment: @Explosion Pills is there a way to make it so that the array only contains 1 match rather than $matches[0] and $matches[1]

Comment: You could use a lookbehind and lookahead: `(?<=')[a-z0-9]+(?=')`.  But why make it harder on yourself when inspecting `$matches[1]` is so easy?

Comment: To elaborate, there is only one match.  `$matches[0]` is the whole match and `$matches[1]` is the part that was captured by the first set of parentheses.  Please do **not** use lookarounds (especially lookbehinds) if you don't have to.  As @ExplosionPills said, you'll save yourself a lot of hassle in the future if you learn to use the tool the way it was meant to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the word in a specific group:

```
\'([A-Za-z0-9]+)\'
```

Comment: @Mr.1.0 As expected. Just use `$result[1]`.